# Waiting for Promise API calls to finish

Tags: javascript, for-loop, async-await, promise, axios

Okay, so I have this function that is a simple Axios request. We know that Axios will run as a promise based request so we do something like this and push all the responses into an array

```
let array = []
function A() {
  return axios.get(url).then(r => r.data).then(r => array.push(r.forms))
}
```

The issue is now I need to call this function specifically 898 times.

```
async function main() {
  await someArrayWithALotOfObjects.forEach(async (e) => {
    return await A(e.url);
  });
  console.log(array);
}
```

The issue is when I run `main()` it console logs `[]`, however when I change the main function to be completely hardcoded it outputs all the data correctly pushed to the array in a workable format.

```
async function main() {
  await A(someArrayWithALotOfObjects[0].url);
  await A(someArrayWithALotOfObjects[1].url);
  await A(someArrayWithALotOfObjects[2].url);
  await A(someArrayWithALotOfObjects[3].url);
  await A(someArrayWithALotOfObjects[4].url);
  await A(someArrayWithALotOfObjects[5].url);
  await A(someArrayWithALotOfObjects[6].url);
  await A(someArrayWithALotOfObjects[7].url);
  ...

  
  console.log(array);
}
```

So my question is how to not hardcode because the loop does not seem to be completed before I run the `console.log` function.

Note: eventually I will be changing the console logging to the fs event for writing to a file if this helps in writing a better solution.

Note2: IDK how to use the new yield stuff in JavaScript yet, so if that is the solution needed forgive me.

Comment: none of the suggested problems that were similarly solved my issue...

Comment: A example for Promise in Series ```const urls = ["url0", "url1", "url2"];

async function run() {
  const result = [];
  for (const url of urls) {
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    result.push(response.data);
  }
  return result;
}

run().then(console.log).catch(console.log);```

Comment: The suggested questions really solve your question. You may have difficulties understanding it then.

Comment: I was able to use the 'for of' option, but I had to add quiet a bit of other code handlers to get it to work.